# Does SQL Server have an equivalent of Excel's KURT function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Excel has the KURT function that returns the kurtosis of a data set. Does SQL Server have an equivalent aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL has all of the functions required to calculate kurtosis, but I think you'd have to put it all together yourself in a custom function.

Here's one implementation I found (ref: [SolidQ](http://blogs.solidq.com/dsarka/Post.aspx?ID=85&title=skewness%20and%20kurtosis%20part%201%20%E2%80%93%20t-sql%20solution))

```
SELECT 
   Kurt = SUM(SQUARE(SQUARE(((Age*1.0-m.mean)/m.[StDev])))) * MIN(m.corrfact2) - MIN(m.subfact)
FROM 
      vTargetMail v 
   CROSS JOIN
      (
       SELECT 
          mean = AVG(Age*1.0), [StDev] = STDEV(Age),
          corrfact2 = COUNT(*)*1.0 * (COUNT(*)+1) / (COUNT(*)-1) / (COUNT(*)-2) / (COUNT(*)-3),
          subfact = 3.0 * SQUARE((COUNT(*)-1)) / (COUNT(*)-2) / (COUNT(*)-3)
       FROM vTargetMail v
      ) AS m;
```

Comment: The provided query will fail: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=a35de768dcd7168e438855974de0a52b) in case of: 1) fewer than 4 values (note division by `COUNT(*) - 1/2/3`  2) when all values are the same(i.e. when standard deviation is 0)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it—it is a obscure function and MySQL tends to implement functions closer to the base core of mathematics only.

However, Kurtosis is fairly straightforward to calculate yourself.  See the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis).

Answer (score 0):

By combine the method from http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/skewness-and-kurtosis-part-1-t-sql-solution/#abh_posts and https://sqlwithpanks.wordpress.com/2016/06/22/kurtosis-a-measure-of-tailedness-of-the-distribution/, the following is a tested work version:

```
;with v as (select floor(rand(convert(varbinary,newid()))*365)+1 as X from dbo.TblModel07_High),
AGG as (SELECT m1 = AVG(X*1.0), sd1 = STDEV(X),corrfact1 = COUNT(*)*1.0 / (COUNT(*)-1) / (COUNT(*)-2),
[corrfact2] = COUNT(*)*1.0 * (COUNT(*)+1) / (COUNT(*)-1) / (COUNT(*)-2) / (COUNT(*)-3),
[subfact] = 3.0 * SQUARE((COUNT(*)-1)) / (COUNT(*)-2) / (COUNT(*)-3) from v)
SELECT N=count(*), Xmin=min(X), Xmax=max(X),M = MIN(m1),SD = MIN(sd1),CV = min(sd1)/min(m1),
Skew = SUM(((X*1.0 - m1)/sd1)*((X*1.0-m1)/sd1)*((X*1.0-m1)/sd1))* min(corrfact1),
Kurt = SUM( SQUARE( SQUARE( ( ( X * 1.0 - m1 )/sd1 ) ) ) ) * min(corrfact2) - min(subfact)+3 from v cross apply
(select m1,sd1,corrfact1,corrfact2,subfact from AGG) A
```